# Python Pandas Syntax Error (Invalid) - Probability

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file IGN.csv. I have to determine:

If a game is selected from data:

Probability of it being "awful" give it was released in year 2015 or 2016. Basically, the sample space n is now games in 2015 or 2016. This is my attempt:

```
#import csv file
data = pd.read_csv('IGN.csv')
n = len(data)

# D.)
modifiedN = len(data[(data['release_year'] == 2015) | (data['release_year'] == 2016)])
successes = len(data[(data['score_phrase' == 'Awful') & ((data['release_year'] == 2015) | (data['release_year'] == 2016))])
print("Probability = successes / n = " + str(successes / modifiedN))
```

First I found the new n, by finding the length of the data of games from 2015 or 2016. Then I tried to find the length of the data of games that are awful, given the conditions that the games  are from 2015 or 2016. But I keep getting invalid syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
len(data[(data['score_phrase' == 'Awful')
```

Should be

```
len(data[(data['score_phrase'] == 'Awful')
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions like this one, their destiny is to be closed and deleted. A comment for the OP is enough.

Comment: If the question is bound to be removed, why does it matter if I post a comment or an answer? Not trying to start a beef, just curious.

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba. In the case of typo question, they generally get closed (which takes 5 votes from users with >3k rep). If there is no answer with a score >0 and no accepted answer, they get automatically deleted after 9 days. If they get an upvote or an accepted answer, they have to be deleted manually by 3 votes (at least) from users with >10k rep, who don't have so many votes to spend each day. So, a lot more work for the community! :)

Comment: Ohh I see that makes sense. Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.